# A couple of overlap issues

Tags: bug, design

Anything involving user cards and badges still seems a bit edgy. For example this guy is running over behind the next one....

[image: badge count cut off]

This is even worse in the moderator stats page where apparently we all get extra fishies?

[image: bonus mod badges]

Comment: Praise Jesus! He has multiplied the fishes!

Comment: The extra fishies signify the presence of talkative and outspoken badges...not sure how the overlap there should be handled, but the school of fish look is kinda fun :)